# C# XNA: Attempting to get player ship to fire

Tags: c#, xna

Im creating an asteroids game and am having an issue trying to get my player ship to fire.
Below is the code for what i believe should get the player ship to fire

```
 public void Fire()
    {
     if (RocketshotDelay >= 0)
            RocketshotDelay--;
        if (RocketshotDelay <= 0)
        {
            rocketshotPosition = new Vector2(rocketshotPosition.X + 32 - rocketshotTexture.Width / 2, rocketshotPosition.Y + 30);

            isVisible = true;

             if (RocketshotDelay == 0)
            RocketshotDelay = 15;

  public void UpdateRocketshot()
 {
  rocketshotPosition.Y = rocketshotPosition.Y - speed;

            if (rocketshotPosition.Y <= 0)
                isVisible = false;
 }
```

I think this should get my player ship to fire but as of yet, i havent been able to get the ship to fire. Any suggestions on any issues in my code would be grateful. Cheers

Comment: Do you draw the shot? Have you checked if the code is executed? Does `Fire()` get called from somewhere?

Comment: Fire() gets called in a seperate update function in the class, so that when the space key is pressed, the fire() method is called

Comment: I'm not fond of the `if (RocketshotDelay >= 0)` followed immediately by a `if (RocketshotDelay <= 0)` in this situation, as you should never have a case where your rocket delay is less than 0 (since you are always decrementing one at a time) unless you are touching that value from elsewhere in your code.  Note that `if (RocketshotDelay == 0)` will never evaluate as true, as that condition is already matched by the top `if` statement.  This means that your setting of `RocketshotDelay = 15;` never happens.

Comment: Also, your brackets are not all present here. Best we can do is guess where the bugs are.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer in the comments yet.

Possible issues:

- Make sure if you're using the "base.Update()" code and "base.Draw()" functions that you have done "Components.Add(*RocketShot Instance Name*)" or "Components.Add(this)"
- Is the firing code located inside of the actual rocketship or rocketshot class?

  - If it is inside of the rocketshot class (which it seems like it is), then ask yourself and see where the initial rocketshot position is.  It seems as though you simply offset it, but where is it being offset from? is the rocketshot perhaps off at x:0 y:0 to begin with? or are you sure it's tracking next to the ship?
- Your rocketshot delay might also not be working correctly.  You only reset the rocketshot to 15 if it is EQUAL to 0. Not if it is less than. But you can trigger that code even if it is -1 or anything else negative. This means that maybe you'll get your first shot, but if the delay goes beyond 0 (-1 to anything else negative), your bullet won't reset. If this happens your rocketshot will probably keep reseting.
- Make sure your speed is reasonable. Maybe first test it with a small number.
- Make sure your trigger and fire code considers a button being *released* and not just pressed and held down. Meaning use a previousKeyState and a currentKeyState. Otherwise it might keep triggering. (And with the delay issue this might cause it to always reset all the time).

  ```
      if (RocketshotDelay <= 0) //This will trigger and reset all the time
          RocketshotDelay = 15;
  ```